# K4W Python Problems in OpenKinect Libfreenect

Tags: python, linux, wrapper, kinect, openkinect

I have installed the K4W branch of the open kinect project on Linux 11.10 from https://github.com/renewagner/libfreenect/tree/k4w-wip . I can navigate to the directory libfreenect/build and run the command:

```
sudo bin/glview
```

and the output works correctly.

I have also installed the Python wrappers from libfreenect/wrappers/python and I can import the libraries successfully.  However if I run a simple code such as

```
import freenect
freenect.sync_get_depth()
```

Which I saved as kinect1.py and then ran using the command `sudo kinect1.py`

I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid Index[0]
>
> Error: Can't open device 1.) Is it plugged in? 2.) Read README

However, I can go straight back to running the glview example and it still work find.  So I must be missing something with the Python wrapper implementation.  I hope someone can help.

Comment: ...did you read `README`? Does it work after running `glview`? Do any examples work? Make sure `glview` is not running!

Comment: Also IIRC `sudo` isn't required to make OpenKinect work.

Comment: I can run glview and that works fine but then running a python script will just give the error above however running glview again still works.  I have tried running the python and the unplugging and reconnecting and trying again and it still gives the same error.

Either you can use SUDO or a rules file.  The rules file is written for Xbox and I tried to rewrite it based on the results of lsusb but I guess that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Huh...maybe I fscked something when I installed it, because I never needed `sudo` :P

Comment: Were you installing the K4W version? Or did you use the installer in the repository?

Comment: Also I am very new to Linux so the chances are I have screwed something up.  But I know I can access the kinect as glview works but Python doesn't...

Comment: Oops! For some reason I didn't understand you were using Linux. I am using OS X. So my experience doesn't apply. Sorry.